# How to use fragments with LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm doing a Android App and I'm having problem when I use LinearLayout in my FragmentActivity with some fragments.

In the XML of my FragmentActivity I'm using LinearLayout with vertical orientation. On the onCreate method I add 3 fragments on this activity. But it show only the first fragment.

If I change LinearLayout to FrameLayout all the fragments are show overlapping each other

Comment: The first fragment will fill the entire `Linearlayout`. Use some containers layouts for each of those fragments in the initial `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Are you trying to show all the three framgnets at the same time or only one fragment at a time?

Comment: post your xml. and relevant snippet of code

Comment: i think the layout_height and the layout_width is set to match_parent or fill_parent. change it to wrap_content or another size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Daniel Gabay is right. The problem was caused because I was using the wrong value for  android:layout_width,android:layout_height